# How to replace values in columns with its mean based on the sequential information from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, time-series

I have time-series data. My task is to average some of values in the feature columns based on the sequences in target column, and then replace those values in feature columns by averaged value for each sequence. So, for example, in the table below, we have a sequence of three 1s in target, we take average of values in this sequence for `feature1` and then for `feature2` and after that we replace those values with our mean values. And that should be done for each sequence in target.

| ID | time(s) | feature1 | feature2 | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 500 | 2.56789 | 91.12834 | 0 |
| abc | 1000 | 2.45678 | 91.23452 | 1 |
| abc | 1500 | 2.36589 | 91.54398 | 1 |
| abc | 2000 | 2.56428 | 91.32348 | 1 |
| abc | 2500 | 2.25869 | 91.79322 | 0 |
| cba | 500 | 5.36589 | 93.54398 | 1 |
| cba | 1000 | 5.56428 | 93.32348 | 1 |
| cba | 1500 | 5.25869 | 94.79322 | 0 |

To do this, I made an algorithm based on indexing.

```
def averaging(input_df: pd.DataFrame):
    output_df = input_df.copy()
    target_index = []
    
    for _, sub_df in input_df.groupby('ID'): 
        _index = sub_df.index
        _targets = sub_df['target'].tolist()

        before = 1 if _targets[0] == 1 else 0

        tmp = []
        if before:
            tmp.append(_index[0])

        for i, flag in enumerate(_targets):
            if flag == 1 and before == 0:
                tmp.append(_index[i]) 
            elif flag == 0 and before == 1:
                tmp.append(_index[i])
                target_index.append(tmp)
                tmp = []
            before = flag
            
        if tmp:
            tmp.append(_index[-1]+1)
            target_index.append(tmp)

    output_df['target_id'] = 0
    for i, (indexi, indexj) in enumerate(target_index):
        output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj]['target_id'] = i+1

    targetid2avg = output_df.loc[output_df['target_id']!=0].groupby('target_id')[['feature1', 'feature2']].mean()
    targetid2avg.columns = ['target_feature1', 'target_feature2']

    output_df = output_df.merge(targetid2avg, on='target_id', how='left')
    output_df.loc[output_df['target_id']!=0, ['feature1', 'feature2']] = output_df.loc[output_df['target_id']!=0, ['target_feature1', 'target_feature2']].values
    
    output_df = output_df.drop(columns=['target_feature1', 'target_feature2'], axis=1)
    
    return output_df
```

However, something goes wrong when I start indexing the `target_id` column in `output_df` and instead of indexes there, I keep getting empty column (zeros). Tried to figure out what the problem is but nothing helped. Does anyone know what is wrong here or how to solve this problem in another way?

Will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is contained in this bit:

```
    output_df['target_id'] = 0
    for i, (indexi, indexj) in enumerate(target_index):
        output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj]['target_id'] = i+1
```

When you run this part, you'll get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj]['target_id'] = i+1
```

What this means essentially, is that you aren't updating the actual DataFrame, you are updating a copy of a slice.

Indeed, after running this line, you'll find that the values in column `target_id` are still all zeros:

```
print(output_df.target_id.sum()) # 0
```

To fix this you could use the following line instead:

```
    output_df['target_id'] = 0
    for i, (indexi, indexj) in enumerate(target_index):
        # output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj]['target_id'] = i+1
        output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj,range(len(output_df.columns))[-1]] = i+1
```

Once you have corrected this line, your function should generate the expected outcome. To be sure, the last bit could also simply be:

```
    for i, (indexi, indexj) in enumerate(target_index):

        means = output_df.loc[indexi:indexj-1,['feature1', 'feature2']].mean(axis=0)
        output_df.loc[indexi:indexj-1,['feature1', 'feature2']] = \
            output_df.loc[indexi:indexj-1,['feature1', 'feature2']].assign(**means)
    
    return output_df
```

Same result. Finally, you could do all of this a bit quicker actually. E.g. using something like this:

```
def averaging_new(input_df: pd.DataFrame):
    output_df = input_df.copy()
    output_df['target_id'] = 0
    
    zeros = output_df.target != 0
    sequences = (zeros != zeros.shift()).cumsum()

    features = ['feature1','feature2']

    gb = output_df[zeros].groupby([sequences, 'ID'])[features].transform('mean')
    gb['target_id'] = output_df[zeros].groupby([sequences, 'ID'])[features].ngroup() + 1
    
    output_df.loc[gb.index, features] = gb[features]
    output_df.loc[gb.index, 'target_id'] = gb['target_id']
    
    return output_df

output_df = averaging_new(input_df)
output_df

    ID  time(s)   feature1   feature2  target  target_id
0  abc      500   2.567890  91.128340       0          0
1  abc     1000   2.462317  91.367327       1          1
2  abc     1500   2.462317  91.367327       1          1
3  abc     2000   2.462317  91.367327       1          1
4  abc     2500   2.258690  91.793220       0          0
5  cba      500   5.465085  93.433730       1          2
6  cba     1000   5.465085  93.433730       1          2
7  cba     1500   5.258690  94.793220       0          0

# comparing that result with your function corrected as well as your function refactored:

def averaging_corrected(input_df: pd.DataFrame):
    output_df = input_df.copy()
    target_index = []
    
    for _, sub_df in input_df.groupby('ID'): 
        _index = sub_df.index
        _targets = sub_df['target'].tolist()

        before = 1 if _targets[0] == 1 else 0

        tmp = []
        if before:
            tmp.append(_index[0])

        for i, flag in enumerate(_targets):
            if flag == 1 and before == 0:
                tmp.append(_index[i]) 
            elif flag == 0 and before == 1:
                tmp.append(_index[i])
                target_index.append(tmp)
                tmp = []
            before = flag
            
        if tmp:
            tmp.append(_index[-1]+1)
            target_index.append(tmp)

    output_df['target_id'] = 0
    for i, (indexi, indexj) in enumerate(target_index):
        # output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj]['target_id'] = i+1
        output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj,range(len(output_df.columns))[-1]] = i+1

    targetid2avg = output_df.loc[output_df['target_id']!=0].groupby('target_id')[['feature1', 'feature2']].mean()
    targetid2avg.columns = ['target_feature1', 'target_feature2']

    output_df = output_df.merge(targetid2avg, on='target_id', how='left')
    output_df.loc[output_df['target_id']!=0, ['feature1', 'feature2']] = output_df.loc[output_df['target_id']!=0, ['target_feature1', 'target_feature2']].values
    
    output_df = output_df.drop(columns=['target_feature1', 'target_feature2'], axis=1)
    
    return output_df

def averaging_refactored(input_df: pd.DataFrame):
    output_df = input_df.copy()
    target_index = []
    
    for _, sub_df in input_df.groupby('ID'): 
        _index = sub_df.index
        _targets = sub_df['target'].tolist()

        before = 1 if _targets[0] == 1 else 0

        tmp = []
        if before:
            tmp.append(_index[0])

        for i, flag in enumerate(_targets):
            if flag == 1 and before == 0:
                tmp.append(_index[i]) 
            elif flag == 0 and before == 1:
                tmp.append(_index[i])
                target_index.append(tmp)
                tmp = []
            before = flag
            
        if tmp:
            tmp.append(_index[-1]+1)
            target_index.append(tmp)

    output_df['target_id'] = 0
    for i, (indexi, indexj) in enumerate(target_index):
        output_df.iloc[indexi:indexj,range(len(output_df.columns))[-1]] = i+1

        means = output_df.loc[indexi:indexj-1,['feature1', 'feature2']].mean(axis=0)
        output_df.loc[indexi:indexj-1,['feature1', 'feature2']] = \
            output_df.loc[indexi:indexj-1,['feature1', 'feature2']].assign(**means)
    
    return output_df

output_df2 = averaging_corrected(input_df)
output_df3 = averaging_refactored(input_df)

dfs = [output_df, output_df2, output_df3]
all(x.equals(dfs[0]) for x in dfs)
# True
```

N.B. in `averaging_new` and `averaging_refactored`, I'm not actually using the column `target_id` to fill the feature columns. Just adding it for the comparison.

Comment: I've almost lost hope for an answer:) It helped and also opened my eyes how else to solve this problem. Thanks for such a comprehensive response! @ouroboros1

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if anything is unclear. (Indeed, one minor thing perhaps is rather confusing: inside `averaging_new()`, it would of course have been much better for me to have called the var `zeros = output_df.target != 0` something like `non_zeros` or `ones`... But no functional difference of course.)